# move a cuboid from start to destination

Tags: geometry, game-theory

[image]

Consider the field with infinitely many boxes, "S" means start, "D" destination, and I already found a way to move a $1\times 2\times 4$-cuboid (as you can see on the right at this picture) from the start position to destination trough tilting this cuboid. My question:

If I choose an arbitrary startposition S and destination D, is it always possible to tilt such an  $1\times 2\times 4$-cuboid from S to D?

Regards

Edit:Ok first question is now clear, thanks to achille hui. What is if the field has only 10x15 units? How to find out a startposition and endposition such that there is no possibility to move the cuboid from start to end? I could try every possibility but it is an overkill. the starting point is always standing up and the end standing up again and the field now has 10x15 units. Maybe there are some problems in the corners. Could you give me a strategy/hint?

Comment: Is the starting point always standing up and the end standing up?

Comment: yes, it is. sorry, I forgot to say this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible.

The key is one can move the initial "standing up / horizontally aligned" position for one unit with only 6 flips in both horizontal and vertical directions (See *elementary moves* at end).

Using them, one can move the cuboid anywhere one want while keeping it "standing up / horizontally aligned". If the end configuration is vertically aligned like what was shown in the question, one can align it with 3 extra steps.

**Elementary moves**

Label the 4 sides of the base of the cuboid by E(ast), N(orth), W(est) and S(outh).
We can index the set of possible operations on the cuboid using strings formed from 4 alphabets: $E, N, W, S$. For example, one can use the string "ENW" as a shorthand for following chain of operations

- first tilt along the E(ast) edge of the cuboid.
- next tilt along the new N(orth) edge.
- finally tilt along the newest W(est) edge.

As shown in the two pictures below, the strings "ESWWNE / SWNNES" 
correspond to a unit move in horizontal and vertical direction respectively.

[image: horizontal moves]
(ESWWNE - a horizonal move to the left for one unit)

[image: vertical moves]
(SWNNES - a vertical moves to the top for one unit )

Comment: thank you, this is helpful (I voted up your answer). I understand the elementary moves and the pictures, but I don't understand the explanation why it is possible. Could you explain it in more detail? Sorry :/. In the first picture, the horizontal move, it is not possible to move from the last position with 1 extra step to the start position, is this a problem? Is this improtant here that the field has infinitely many boxes? I think yes, if the start and endposition could be arbitrary.

Comment: Let's limit ourselves to those end configurations which are horizontally aligned. We can index them by the coordinates $(x_e,y_e)$ on its lower left corner. If we start from a configuration whose lower left corner is at $(x,y) = (0,0)$. The horizontal move allow us to increase/decrease the $x$ by one unit. The vertical move allow us to increase the $y$ by one unit. So with $|x_e| + |y_e|$ elementary moves, we can move the cuboid to its end configuration. Yes, having infinitely many boxes is important. I'm not 100% sure whether we can move the cuboid correctly near the boundaries.

Comment: BTW, I don't understand the part of your question about "the last position with 1 extra step."

Comment: I still don't understand this..:( What is the meaning/the importance of the second possibility (SWNNES) ?

Comment: Oh wait, now I understand! At the moment I write everything down and I'm elaborating this. Thank you very much! This was realy helpful!!

Comment: The first move ESWWNE allow you to move horizontally, the second move SWNNES allow you to move vertically. You need both of them (or one of them plus 3 moves that  flip a horizontally aligned configuration to a vertically aligned one) in order to move your cuboid over the whole plane.

Comment: ok, meanwhile I understand everything. Do you know, if such a sequence of moves to move the initial position for one unit is unique? I try to specify my question: If I want to move the initial position for one unit, for example the same unit as we can see in the first picture, is there an other possibility as this sequence of moves you proposed to move the same initial position for one unit? I hope it's understandable, because my english is bad, sorry.

Comment: this pictures, your answer and the describtions are really good, thank you! And very helpful too! If it's better to seperate the new question above/ open a new question for this question above, I will do it

Comment: No, there are infinite many moves that can move the block horizontally or vertically for $\pm 1$ unit. However, the above moves are minimal in terms of the number of steps. There are two moves with at most 6 steps ENWWSE, ESWWNE which move the block to the east, two moves WNEESW WSEENW to the west, SENNWS, SWNNES to the north and two moves WSEENW, NESSWN to the south.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much!!

Comment: I have a last question. If you want I can open a new question on mse. Do you know if the same is possible if the field has only 10x15 units?  I think no, I think if start and endpostion are located in one of the corner, it could be problematic but I'm not sure. If I want to find a start and an endposition with there is no possibility to flip the cuboid from start to end, my only idea is to try out every possibility. But it is an overkill. Do you have an idea how to do it?